# Unable to track why string permutations are not being appended in a global variable for array permutations

Tags: python, string, algorithm, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I am trying to code the String permutation problem. Instead of string I have a list of integers like [1,2,3]. I have to print out all possible permutations of the list. However, there's some issue with my code that I'm not able to figure out. Somehow, the line `if not in words` in the base case hits only once. I'm trying to figure this out from the past one hour. Any help would be appreciated!. TIA
Here's the code

```
words = list()  
def permute(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return None

    l = 0
    r = len(nums)

    permute_helper(nums,0,r)

def permute_helper(nums,start,end):
    current = 0
    if start == end-1:
        if not nums in words:
            print 'appended'
            words.append(nums)   
    else:
        for current in range(start,end):
            temp = nums[start]
            nums[start] = nums[current]
            nums[current] = temp
            #Recursive call
            permute_helper(nums,start+1,end)
            temp = nums[start]
            nums[start] = nums[current]
            nums[current] = temp

permute([1,2,3])
print words
```

Comment: Use itertools...

Comment: Thanks. I'll update it

Comment: Much better. Thanks. :-)

Comment: change `words.append(nums)` to `words.append(nums[:])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is that you keep modifying the same list `nums` so you end up with only one copy that was modified but the modifications were not recorded.

Change:

```
words.append(nums)
```

to:

```
words.append(nums[:])
```

which will create a copy of `nums` and "freeze" it current state.

**Comment:**
You can do the swap in a more pythonic way, instead of:

```
temp = nums[start]
nums[start] = nums[current]
nums[current] = temp
```

do:

```
nums[start], nums[current] = nums[current], nums[start]
```

Comment: Thanks. That was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You're appending the same list each time. No wonder it's already there (`in words`).

In other words, you are not collecting each different permutation, but a reference to `nums`. So, subsequent permutations are reflected in `words`. That's the plague of mutability.

One solution is to make a copy of the current permutation:

```
words.append(nums[:])
```

By the way, a pythonic swap is:

```
a, b = b, a   # no need for tmp
```

Also, there is no need to reset `current`.